# Laravel: Get similar posts by percentage of presence of tags

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the `Post` and the `Tag` models. One `Post` can have multiple `Tag` and can be later accessed by `$post->tags`. Now, I want to use the tags to fetch similar posts by tags presence percentage. Here's the scenario:

Current post tags: `tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag5`

Similar post 1: `tag2, tag3, tag4, tag6, tag7` - contains 3 tags (60%)

Similar post 2: `tag1, tag2, tag3, tag7` - contains 3 tags (60%)

Non-similar post: `tag1, tag22, tag33, tag44` - contains only 1 tag (20%)

Let's say I want to have 60% (from the current post) similarity between tags and I want to fetch them on MySQL level. How do I do it?

Comment: I don't know what post and tag models are. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

For similar posts get the tag count with posts list and current post tags. Apply  orderby tag count desc and limit to how many similar posts you want to get.

use withCount function like

```
$current_tags=$post->tags->pluck('id');

$similar_posts=Post::withCount('tags')->join('tags','posts.id','=','tags.post_id')-`>whereIn('tag_id',$current_tags)->groupBy('posts.id')->orderBy('tags_count')-`>limit(5)->get();
```